# Impossible to initialize a preformatted HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I bought a preformatted (NTFS) external drive and I want to re-format it with APFS using High Sierra (last upgrade).
It is impossible. Whatever is the file system chosen, I always gat an error.
What can I do? this is the second HD I bought. Different manufacturer, different capacity, but same problem.
Thanks.
Federico

Comment: Yes. If I do that Utility disk is unable to see the HD. even try to remove everything using a widows machine (that is perfectly able to reformat the disk using exFat or NTFS) but when I'm back to mac I'm always getting some error.

Comment: Try zero-ing out the whole disk:  In Terminal issue the command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=dev/rdiskX` where `X` is the identifier of the disk in question.  You may need to issue the command `diskutil list` to determine it if you don't know what it is.  After that, try again.